# Access data on outlook.com using Outlook Rest API

Tags: outlook-restapi

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/use-outlook-rest-api#RegAuthAzure , the only option to access data in Outlook.com using REST API is to use v2 app model which is in preview. Is there no other way to access data on Outlook.com.

Also Microsoft Azure only supports Office365 and not outlook.com. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into issues trying to use the REST API's with an Outlook.com account and in my experience you are correct that the only way to use the REST API's with an Outlook.com account is by using the v2 app model.

I was using the v1 (or non v2) app model and could not get an Outlook.com email address to authenticate with my app, even if I added it as an external user to my AAD. As soon as I switched over to the v2 app model everything worked as it should. It think this in particular is the main feature of the v2 app model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. You need to use the v2 model to access outlook.com accounts.